# Create a field programatically with let me to introduce two values

Tags: 7, entities

I don't want to use field_collection ;) I'll be easy.

I want to build a module that create a a field that let me to save two values at the same time, name and date.

I'd like to have both in the same table, but I don't find any article that explain how to make/define it.

It will be a field with two fields to fill in a node.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) and look through the *Field Example* module.

It contains extensive code examples that show you in detail how to create a custom field, widget and formatter.

Comment: Yes, but examples only play with one field no with two fields. And I remember that in d6 it was black magick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom compound fields in cck. I found following article for Drupal 7 [Compound fields in Drupal 7](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/) , you may get a clear idea from this article how to get proceed.

Previously i have tried [this](http://poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module) D6 tutorial, and created a compound field. i have not tried yet in D7

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my library, thanks to "Drupal 7 module development" I found what I was looking for.

The chapter to build a new field explain how to build a field with 2 o 3 database-fields, more easy than drupal 6 :)